# How to search database with using uuid?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I am using phoenix-framework with postgresql.

For implementing search functionality, I used `ilike` ecto query and all of search functions work fine. For example, I have a function for searching products with product name and it works great.

```
def item_searh_results(language_id, name) do
  from(p in ItemLanguage, where: p.language_id == ^language_id 
                                and ilike(p.name, ^("%#{name}%")),
                        select: %{id: p.item_id,
                                  name: p.name}) |> Repo.all
end
```

I have a model, `Sales` and it uses `uuid` for its primary key.

I am trying to search sales by using `ilike` ecto query api like above function. So I made similar query.

```
from(p in Sales, where: ilike(p.id, ^("%#{id}%")))|> Repo.all
```

However, it returns an error that `** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42883 (undefined_function): operator does not exist: uuid ~~* unknown`

Is it possible to use `ilike` query to search ? If it is, what am I doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to do a substring search in the hex representation of a UUID (e.g. `"%a%"` should match and `"%e%"` should not match for `015cd1d7-2794-4247-a24f-16b84ca9a3ac`). You can do this by explicitly converting the UUID value to `text` and then doing `ilike`:

```
from(p in Sales, where: ilike(fragment("?::text", p.id), ^"%#{id}%")) |> Repo.all
```

(I also removed a redundant set of parentheses around the search string.)

Comment: Yes, thats how I want to search. Now I understand that in order to search with UUID, I need to convert it to `text`. I just tried your solution, but it triggers an error that `type(p.id(), :text)` is not a valid query expression.. is there any other way to convert it to text ?

Comment: Could you please give the edited version a try? I switched `type` to `fragment`. Pretty sure this should work.